# How do restore a web socket connection in Swift when I turn off then turn on my WiFi connection?

Tags: ios, swift, websocket

I have an iOS app in Swift which uses a web socket to fetch live stock prices from a public API. I want to be able to restore the web socket connection when I turn off WiFi and turn it back on again. I have tried placing;

```
webSocketTask.resume()
```

in methods called when the WiFi connection is turned off but that doesn't work.

Here is my singleton class and method for fetching the live stock price information.

```
protocol NetworkServicesDelegateProtocol: AnyObject {
    func sendStockInfo(stocksInfo: [String: StockInfo], isConnected: Bool)
}

class NetworkServices: NSObject, URLSessionWebSocketDelegate {
    
    static let sharedInstance = NetworkServices()
    
    var webSocketTask: URLSessionWebSocketTask?
    
    var stocksInfo: [String: StockInfo] = [:]
    
    var socketResults: [String: [StockInfo]] = [:]
    
    weak var delegate: NetworkServicesDelegateProtocol?
    
    var isConnected = true
    
    var timer: Timer?
    
    var stockSymbols: [String] = []
    
    func fetchStockInfo(symbols: [String], delegate: CompanyPriceListVC) {
        
        stockSymbols = symbols
        
        self.delegate = delegate
                        
        let urlSession = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
        
        webSocketTask = urlSession.webSocketTask(with: FINNHUB_SOCKET_STOCK_INFO_URL!)
                
        webSocketTask!.resume()
        
        for symbol in symbols {
            
            let string = FINNHUB_SOCKET_MESSAGE_STRING + symbol + "\"}"
            
            let message = URLSessionWebSocketTask.Message.string(string)
            
            webSocketTask!.send(message) { error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("DEBUG: Error sending message: \(error)")
                }

                self.receiveMessage()
                
            }
        }
    }
            
    private func receiveMessage() {
        
        self.webSocketTask!.receive { result in
                    
            switch result {
            case .failure(let error):
                print("DEBUG: Error receiving message: \(error)")
                self.webSocketTask?.resume()
                
            case .success(.string(let jsonData)):

                guard let stockData = jsonData.data(using: .utf8) else { return }
                
                self.socketResults = [:]
                self.stocksInfo = [:]
                
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                do {
                    let socketData = try decoder.decode(SocketData.self, from: stockData)
                    guard let stockInfoData = socketData.data else { return }
                    for stockInfo in stockInfoData {
                        let symbol = stockInfo.symbol
                        if self.socketResults[symbol] == nil {
                            self.socketResults[symbol] = [StockInfo]()
                        }
                        self.socketResults[symbol]?.append(stockInfo)
                    }
                    
                    for (symbol, stocks) in self.socketResults {
                        for item in stocks {
                            if self.stocksInfo[symbol] == nil {
                                self.stocksInfo[symbol] = item
                            } else if item.timestamp > self.stocksInfo[symbol]!.timestamp {
                                self.stocksInfo[symbol] = item
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                    self.delegate?.sendStockInfo(stocksInfo: self.stocksInfo, isConnected: self.isConnected)
                    
                    self.receiveMessage()
                    
                } catch {
                    print("Error converting JSON: \(error)")
                }
                
            default:
                print("default")
            }
        }
    }

    func closeWebSocketConnection() {
        webSocketTask?.cancel(with: .goingAway, reason: nil)
    }
    
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, webSocketTask: URLSessionWebSocketTask, didCloseWith closeCode: URLSessionWebSocketTask.CloseCode, reason: Data?) {
        
        let reasonString: String
        if let reason = reason, let string = String(data: reason, encoding: .utf8) {
            reasonString = string
        } else {
            reasonString = ""
        }
        
        print("DEBUG: didCloseWith called: close code is \(closeCode), reason is \(String(describing: reasonString))")
    }
    
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
        
        if let error = error {
            print("DEBUG: didCompleteWithError called: error = \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, webSocketTask: URLSessionWebSocketTask, didOpenWithProtocol protocol: String?) {
        print("DEBUG: didOpenWithProtocol called")
        ping()
    }
    
    func ping() {
        
        webSocketTask?.sendPing { error in
            
        if let error = error {
            print("DEBUG: Error when sending PING \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            print("DEBUG: Web socket connection is alive")
            self.isConnected = true
            self.timer?.invalidate()
            self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 6.0, repeats: false) { timer in
                
                
                // Alert user that connection is lost
                print("DEBUG: Connection is lost")
                self.isConnected = false
                self.delegate?.sendStockInfo(stocksInfo: self.stocksInfo, isConnected: self.isConnected)
                
                // Restart connection
                self.webSocketTask?.resume()
                
                // Update connection status
                self.isConnected = true
                print("DEBUG: Connection is restored")
                
                // start sending messages through the socket again
                for symbol in self.stockSymbols {
                    
                    let string = FINNHUB_SOCKET_MESSAGE_STRING + symbol + "\"}"
                    let message = URLSessionWebSocketTask.Message.string(string)
                    
                    // send the next message
                    self.webSocketTask!.send(message) { error in
                        if let error = error {
                            print("DEBUG: Error sending message: \(error)")
                        }

                        self.receiveMessage()
                    }
                }
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
                self.ping()
            }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

I have a `ping()` method which detects when connection is lost by invoking a timer's completion code if no pong is received 5 seconds after sending a ping.

I get these error messages when I turn off then turn on WiFi;

```
DEBUG: didOpenWithProtocol called
DEBUG: Web socket connection is alive
DEBUG: Web socket connection is alive
DEBUG: Web socket connection is alive
DEBUG: Connection is lost
DEBUG: Connection is restored
DEBUG: Error when sending PING The operation couldn’t be completed. (kNWErrorDomainPOSIX error 53 - Software caused connection abort)
DEBUG: Error receiving message: The operation couldn’t be completed. (kNWErrorDomainPOSIX error 65 - No route to host)
DEBUG: Error receiving message: The operation couldn’t be completed. (kNWErrorDomainPOSIX error 65 - No route to host)
DEBUG: didCompleteWithError called: error = Error Domain=kNWErrorDomainPOSIX Code=65 "No route to host" UserInfo={NSDescription=No route to host, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
```

Comment: I don't think you can directly resume the web socket connection by trying to ping it after a disconnect. Once it is lost, you will need to re-establish the websocket connection first and then start ping/pong. So I believe all the tasks in `fetchStockInfo` will have to performed again to re-establish the connection.